# Group Admin kicked out of own group

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Why does Whatsapp kick me out of group of whcih i am admin and other groups in am in. I changed from Samsung S4 to J3. And how can i restore my previous backups?

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to change your phone number of your whatsapp account, whatsapp recognises your account as a different from initial one.
Your account therefore gets considered as not being among the group members.